# Jszip creating multiple folders

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jszip

zip name:testing.zip

when i am extracting am getting the files
 testing\https_\s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com\files\image.jpg

expected structure :testing/image.jpg

here is my code

```
            var urls = ['https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/files/image.jpg'];

            var nombre = $scope.meetingName;
            //The function is called
            compressed_img(urls, nombre);

            function compressed_img(urls, nombre) {
                var zip = new JSZip();
                var count = 0;
                var name = nombre + ".zip";
                urls.forEach(function (url) {
                    JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        zip.file(url, data, { binary: true });
                        count++;
                        if (count == urls.length) {
                            zip.generateAsync({ type: 'blob' }).then(function (content) {
                                saveAs(content, name);
                            });
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally here is the working code

```
 zip.file(url, data, { binary: true });
```

replaced by

```
 var filename = url.replace(/.*\//g, "");
 zip.file(filename, data, { binary: true, createFolders: true });
```